# адреса переменных, которые мы выводим должны выводиться по возрастанию или по убыванию?

Tags: c++, указатели

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

привет, вопрос:
адреса переменных, которые мы выводим должны выводиться по возрастанию или по убыванию?
на это как-то влияет компилятор, операционная система, её разрядность?
в некоторых примерах(статьях, видео уроках) я видел как адреса выводятся по убыванию, запустив код с этих же примеров(он на картинке) у меня адреса выводятся по возрастанию.

Comment: На это влияют компилятор, его версия, разрядность и флаги оптимизации.

Comment: Изображения не видно

Answer (score 9):

Никакого "должны" тут нет в принципе. Расположение независимых переменных в памяти никак не оговаривается ни языком, ни конкретными реализациями. Конкретное решение принимает, разумеется, компилятор, но никакого фиксированного детерминистического алгоритма для принятия таких решений не экспонируется.